# update an existing column in pyspark without changing older values

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to update an existing column in pyspark but seems like old values in the column are getting updated as well despite no otherwise condition

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+
|cntry|cde_1|cde_2|rsn_1|rsn_2|FLAG|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+
|   MY|    A|     |    1|    2|null|
|   MY|    G|     |    1|    2|null|
|   MY|     |    G|    1|    2|null|
|   TH|    A|     |   16|    2|null|
|   TH|    B|     |    1|   16|   1|
|   TH|     |    W|   16|    2|   1|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+
```

```
df = sc.parallelize([ ["MY","A","","1","2"], ["MY","G","","1","2"], ["MY","","G","1","2"],  ["TH","A","","16","2"], ["TH","B","","1","16"], ["TH","","W","16","2"] ]).toDF(("cntry", "cde_1", "cde_2", "rsn_1", "rsn_2"))


df = df.withColumn('FLAG', F.when( (df.cntry == "MY") &  ( (df.cde_1.isin("G") ) |  (df.cde_2.isin("G") ) )   &  ( (df.rsn_1 == "1") | (df.rsn_2 == "1") ) , 1))

df = df.withColumn('FLAG', F.when( (df.cntry == "TH") &  ( (df.cde_1.isin("B", "W") ) |  (df.cde_2.isin("B", "W") ) )  & ( (df.rsn_1 == "16") |  (df.rsn_2 == "16") ) , 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine your conditions using the Boolean OR. Like this:

```py
df = sc.parallelize([ ["MY","A","","1","2"], ["MY","G","","1","2"], ["MY","","G","1","2"], ["TH","A","","16","2"], ["TH","B","","1","16"], ["TH","","W","16","2"] ]).toDF(("cntry", "cde_1", "cde_2", "rsn_1", "rsn_2"))
cond1 = (df.cntry == "MY") & ( (df.cde_1.isin("G") ) | (df.cde_2.isin("G") ) ) & ( (df.rsn_1 == "1") | (df.rsn_2 == "1") )
cond2 = (df.cntry == "TH") & ( (df.cde_1.isin("B", "W") ) | (df.cde_2.isin("B", "W") ) ) & ( (df.rsn_1 == "16") | (df.rsn_2 == "16") )
df.withColumn("FLAG", F.when(cond1 | cond2, 1)).show()
```

In your last line, you *overwrite* the `FLAG` column, as you’re not referencing its previous state. That’s why the previous values are not preserved.

Instead of combining the expressions, you could also use `when(cond1, 1).otherwise(when(cond2, 1))`. That’s a stylistic choice.